# Select data that has values within 2%?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of student fitness assessment results.  I need to find students who have taken the pre and post test.  In order to get credit the students need to have the pre and post test body fat results within 2%. Here is my working query so far but it doesn't take into account the 2% difference between pre and post bodyfat results.  How would that part of the query be added?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT studid, percentFat, ID1, ID2, STR_TO_DATE(TestDate, '%m/%d/%Y') as testd, bodpoints FROM bodpod, points WHERE ID2 = 'summer2' AND studid != '' GROUP BY studid HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT ID1 ) =2 AND YEAR( testd ) = '2013'
```

Here is the data I'm working with:

-- Table structure for table `bodpod`

```
CREATE TABLE `bodpod` (
  `studid` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `TestDate` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `ID1` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `ID2` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `percentFat` varchar(50) default NULL,
   KEY `studid` (`studid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

-- Dumping data for table `bodpod`

```
INSERT INTO `bodpod` VALUES('123456', '7/29/2013 1:28:24 PM', 'pre', 'summer2', '22.3');
INSERT INTO `bodpod` VALUES('123456', '7/29/2013 1:22:23 PM', 'post', 'summer2', '15');
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you restructured your database to have a column for pre and post, they you could use:

`SELECT * ... WHERE (pre < 1.02*post) AND (post < 1.02*pre) ...`

MySQL will prevent you selecting using calculated columns with `GROUP BY`.